# hide DIV when radio button is clicked with Javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button, hide

I want to hide my div when a radio button is clicked, but cannot figure it out for the life of me.. Here is my code:

```
 <li>
     Residential&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <input type="radio" name="fee" id="residential" class="app_fee"
            value="<?php echo "$applicationFee_residential" ?>"
            onChange="mech_application.fee1.value = eval(mech_application.residential.value)"
            <?php if (isset($_POST['fee'])) {
                      print($residentialYes ? "CHECKED" : "");
            } ?> />
 </li>

 <li>
     Apartment/Commercial
     <input type="radio" name="fee" id="apartment" class="app_fee"
            value="<?php echo "$applicationFee_Apartment" ?>"
            onChange="mech_application.fee1.value = eval(mech_application.apartment.value)"
            <?php if (isset($_POST['fee'])) {
                      print($apartmentNo ? "CHECKED" : "");
            } ?> />
 </li>

 <li>
     Revision&nbsp;
     <input type="radio" name="fee" id="revision" class="app_fee"
            value="<?php echo "$revision" ?>"
            onChange="mech_application.fee1.value = eval(mech_application.revision.value)"
            <?php if (isset($_POST['revision'])) {
                      print($revisionYes ? "CHECKED" : "");
            } ?> />
     <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
               if (!isset($_POST['fee'])) {
                   $problem = TRUE;
                   print '<p class="error">Please select the application type</p>';
                   $error = TRUE;
                }
           }?>
  </li>
```

And I want to hide this div when either Residential or Apartment or clicked, and show it when revision is clicked:

```
 <div class="revision_hidden">
     Application ID:
     <input type="text" name="revision_application_id" size="12" maxlength="40"
            value="<?php if (isset($_POST['revision_application_id'])) {
                             print htmlspecialchars($_POST['revision_application_id']);
                    } ?>"
            placeholder="Application ID"/>
 </div>
```

Any and all help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2YCx3/1/
just found this link on stackoverflow!!!!

Comment: Anything at this point.. haha

Comment: `eval()`!? gaaaahhhh horrible....

Comment: What does mech_application.residential.value returns ?

Comment: I have the value of that input set to a PHP variable which has a value of 0. Then that onBlue function outputs the 0 inside a readonly text box.. I used the PHP variable so it was easier to change the value of the box for people who aren't good with PHP

Comment: I cannot get that to work.. :/ I have PHP outputting a 0 into the value for the revision check box, could that be stopping it from working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your div an id:

```
<div class="revision_hidden" id="my_div"> ...
```

Add an onclick function to your radiobuttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="fee" id="residential" onclick="my_function(this)" ...
<input type="radio" name="fee" id="apartment" onclick="my_function(this)" ...
<input type="radio" name="fee" id="revision" onclick="my_function(this)" ...
```

And add a JavaScript function:

```
function my_function(elm)
{
    if(elm == document.getElementById('residential') || elm == document.getElementById('apartment'))
    {
        //document.getElementById('my_div').style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById('my_div').style.display = "none";
    }
    else if(elm == document.getElementById('revision'))
    {
        //document.getElementById('my_div').style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById('my_div').style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to hide elements real easy.

```
$('#id_of_div').hide()
```

For doing something on the radio button being clicked, use more jQuery

```
$('#id_of_radioBtn').clicked(function(){
   //do something
});
```

Comment: Just put the .hide function inside fof that? sorry I am extremely new.. Can you show me the code?